# Crash when disabling bluedroid

Tags: bluetooth, esp32

i have an ESP32 and i want to use deepsleep when it's not used. Before sending it to sleep i clean up everything, so disconnect, deinitialize and disable everything i build before. But i get a crash when i try to disable bluedroid. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

```cpp
void bt_deinit() {
    
    Serial.println("Deinit AVRC");
    if (esp_avrc_ct_deinit() != ESP_OK)
        Serial.write("Failed to deinit avrc");

    Serial.println("Deinit A2DP");
    if (esp_a2d_source_deinit() != ESP_OK)
        Serial.println("Failed to deinit a2dp");

    Serial.println("disable bluedroid");
    if (esp_bluedroid_disable() != ESP_OK)
        Serial.println("Failed to disable bluedroid");

    Serial.println("Deinit bluedroid");
    if (esp_bluedroid_deinit() != ESP_OK)
        Serial.println("Failed to deinit bluedroid");

    Serial.println("Stop BT");
    if (btStop() == false)
        Serial.println("Failed to stop bt");
}
```

output:

```
Port closed
Uploading to I/O board
Opening port
Port open
Hello there!
Bluetooth init success
good night
Deinit AVRC
Deinit A2DP
disable bluedroid
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:719 (xQueueGenericSend)- assert failed!
abort() was called at PC 0x4008de6f on core 0

Backtrace: 0x40091918:0x3ffce3b0 0x40091b49:0x3ffce3d0 0x4008de6f:0x3ffce3f0 0x4013bfb6:0x3ffce430 0x4013c5f6:0x3ffce460 0x400fdbe2:0x3ffce480 0x400fdc35:0x3ffce4a0 0x400fe12e:0x3ffce4c0 0x400f6bd9:0x3ffce4e0 0x4008e559:0x3ffce510

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8
Hello there!
Bluetooth init success
```

it works fine if i just do not deinitialize everything and send him directly to sleep. But this is not the elegant way.

Comment: upvote for well presented question ... sadly I do not have the expertise to help you ..... perhaps something has not finished shutting down .... insert a delay before disabling bluedroid .... maybe it is the order of events ..... maybe stop first, then disable .... possibly the reverse order of the startup sequence

Answer (score 1):

decoded backtrace in your question is missing, one of the choices to see stack trace is https://github.com/littleyoda/EspStackTraceDecoder

i dont know exactly if this is your case or not, but calling esp_ble_gap_stop_scanning() before esp_bluedroid_deinit() possibly avoids your crash.